# Is list(set(...)) guaranteed to make the same list?

Tags: python, list, set

In python if I have a list with numbers, that may have repeats, if I do the following am I guaranteed to get the same result?

```
l = #some list...

new_list = list(set(l))
```

I have tried it several times and it has given me the same result every time but I'm wondering if that is guaranteed.  By same list I mean the same elements in the same order

Comment: Define "same list"? Do you mean the same ordering? Or just the same elements in any order?

Comment: The order of the elements in the set won't change *until you restart Python* and hash randomisation is enabled, which is the default for Python 3.3 and up, or can be enabled for Python 2.6.8 and up.

Comment: @Ffisegydd sorry I wasn't clear about that, I mean the same ordering

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have duplicates, then no:

```
In [1]: l = [1,1,1]

In [2]: print list(set(l))
[1]
```

And the order can change as well:

```
In [5]: l = [3,2,1]

In [6]: print list(set(l))
[1, 2, 3]
```